# How to change alignment of form buttons?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to change the alignment of buttons in AX 2012
I have 4 buttons in a Button Group in Form It looks like

```
Button1    Button4
Button2    
Button3
```

I want to move Button3 in 2nd column something like

```
Button1    Button3
Button2    Button4
```

Answer (score 4):

Try putting the buttons in a regular `Group` form control using "Vertical" with 2 columns.

Comment: To force the window into a certain structure I use the Group control a lot.

Comment: Regular Groups are the way to go to force design layouts.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your solution and will update the question ASAP.